# Remove list for list

Tags: python, list, append

I receive a list in a list on this example:

```
   y.append([x for x in range(0,6)])
```

The result:
[[0,1,2,3,4,5]]
How can I remove one []?

Comment: Dont append the list.

Comment: Use `y.extend` rather than `y.append`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y.extend([x for x in range(0,6)])
```

or if you want to assign it to another value

```
a = [x for x in range(0,6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
    y.append([x for x in range(0,6)])
    new_list = y[0]
```

new list will be the first list bit without one set of braces